# changing the font size of InfoBox labels in google maps with zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating labels on google map, but I want to change the size of the text with respect to zoom level.
Here is the fiddle that I have tried. http://jsfiddle.net/zzhy/frnLkrc9/3/

```
function createLabel(labelText){

        var myOptions = {
             content: labelText
            ,boxStyle: {
               border: "3px solid black"
              ,textAlign: "center"
              ,fontSize: "18pt"
              ,width: "50px"
             }
            ,disableAutoPan: true
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, 0)
            ,position:  new google.maps.LatLng(39.300299, 34.471664)
            ,closeBoxURL: ""
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "mapPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: true
        };

        var ibLabel = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        ibLabel.open(map);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener to check for zoom_change, then update the box style.  Something like this would work:

```js
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function () {
         if (map.getZoom() >= 6){
              createNewLabel();
         }
         if (map.getZoom() <= 2) createLabel();

        });
```